# .condarc file updated for proxies but still cannot download packages

Tags: proxy, anaconda, conda

I am working behind a Company Proxy and I wanted to install packages in anaconda. I tried it by generating the .condarc file and updating it for Proxy. Even after i included the Proxy it does not work and throws the error as below in Conda prompt. I have also included my .condarc file .I have included the correct proxies. But it does not work. Any suggestions?

```
(base) C:\Users\z103684>pip install virtualenv

Collecting virtualenv

 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028B1F7EC908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte')': /simple/virtualenv/
```

## #

```
ssl_verify: true
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - r
  - defaults
auto_update_conda: true
proxy_servers:
  http: http://************************
  https: https://********************** 
channel_priority: disabled
```

Comment: `.condarc` is the config file for `conda` - if you want to use pip, you need to pass the proxy settings to pip.

Comment: Am using it for the anaconda. I think so this command can also be used in Conda. but it does not work